# How to make a horizontal scroll with transition?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I get stuck to add animated transition on the background carousels.

I am trying to create like pepsi.com website.

e.x: https://www.pepsi.com/#!products/diet-pepsi-caffeine-free
When you click on the button right / left they will shows transition.

This is my trial: https://codepen.io/dimassmacip/pen/yLMEJwp

Expected :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZjGTwtaSiVEVipB3uVEgLPQUAcppr48C/view

Please Help me.

```js
$(".cta").click(function() {
  $(".transition").toggleClass("anim-trans");
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: arial;
}

.transition {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background: #d6d6d6;
  transform: skewX(-5deg) translateX(-50px);
  transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 200px 0 0 200px;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 300px;
}

.cta {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #202020;
  color: #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
}

.anim-trans {
  animation: anim 4s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {}
  20% {
    z-index: 11;
    \transform: skewX(5deg) translateX(-100%);
  }
  40% {
    transform: skewX(0deg) translateX(0);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 11;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #eaeaea;
  }
  60% {
    transform: skewX(3deg) translateX(0);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 11;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #eaeaea;
  }
  80% {
    transform: skewX(1deg) translateX(-100%);
    width: 60%;
    z-index: 11;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #eaeaea;
  }
  100% {
    transform: skewX(-5deg) translateX(-50px);
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="transition"></div>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  <button class="cta">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need to give a lot more information about what a "wave effect or water effect" is exactly.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The pepsi example you mentioned shows no wave-effect, only a horizontal scroll with transition...

Comment: @biberman : My Bad, sorry i mean horizontal scroll with transition.

Comment: Does that mean that you want to change the vertical scroll that your code currently has to a horizontal scroll?

Comment: @biberman: No, I just want to add a water or waves effect like pepsi website. If you see on the pepsi website : https://www.pepsi.com/#!products/diet-pepsi-caffeine-free
On the carousel section.

Comment: @biberman : like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZjGTwtaSiVEVipB3uVEgLPQUAcppr48C/view

Comment: Your image from drive.google.com is the only one that looks like a wave. But it is static and has no movement like (horizontal) scroll. Therefor besides copying that image or building it as SVG i cannot recommend something...

Comment: @biberman: If you look at pepsi site, you will see the movement, that wave that i mean before.